# Filtering a Collection With Backbone MV*

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I have a collection of transactions that have amount, description, type(debit/credit) and categories (home, auto, misc, etc). I'm trying to filter out my results to show only 'home' category in this example. I have my other view working to display all results from my collection. Below I tried to create a new collection 'results' and then output this to my handlebars template.

```
render: function () {
    var results = this.collection.where({category: "home"});
    var filteredCollectionHome = new Backbone.Collection(results);

    this.$el.html(this.template({filteredCollectionHome: this.collection.homeView(true)}));
}
```

The homeView is inside my collections file.

```
homeView: function (toJSON) {
        this.sortByDate(-1); // descending so latest are first

        if(!toJSON) {
            return this.models;
        } else {
            var models = this.models,
                idx = -1,
                json = [],
                model;

            while(model = models[++idx]) {
                json.push(model.attributes);
            }
            return json;
        }   

    },
```

Comment: I think you need to use findWhere, instead of just where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method in your collection which filters the data you want and return a new collection with filtered results.

```
var Transactions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Transaction,

  byCategory: function(name) {
    filtered = this.filter(function(trans) {
      return trans.get("category") === name;
      });
    return new Transactions(filtered);
  }

});

var home_transactions = Transactions.byCategory("home")
```

Comment: So in my render function I use that last line of code you gave me and tried throwing it into my this.$el.html*this.template(home_transactions)); Im' getting 0 results. I logged home_transactions prior to this and I got an object with 1 array inside of it. But it's not outputting to my template. My template is          template:Handlebars.compile($('#all-transactions-template').html())

Comment: home_transactions will return an array of models. You will need to iterate through it and output the desired value

Comment: In your template.. example if your using underscore.  <% _.each(home_transactions, function(trans) { trans.get('description')) }); %>  or you can pre format it in your view and then output it in your template.

Comment: The idea behind what you're saying makes sense. But after working on this for tiresome hours today I need to take a break and look at it tomorrow.